# sys.argv interferes with importing pyplot in emacs interpreter

Tags: python, matplotlib, emacs, import

I am running a python interpreter inside the Emacs program. I am trying to execute a script which, among other things, contains the statement `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`. Since the script takes command-line arguments I set the `sys.argv` variable in the interpreter before calling `execfile`. In this case, I receive an error from the `import pyplot` statement: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'`.

However, if I first `import pyplot` independently in the interpreter and *then* `import sys` to set `sys.argv`, followed by `execfile`, everything runs smoothly.

Why is this?

P.S.: The exact `AttributeError` seems to depend on the element `sys.argv[-1]`. In the above example, it was an integer. If it's a string, then the error is `'module' has no attribute 'cbook'`.